# What is this? (Facebook Offline Conversions API) Error #21009 - The data set upload is temporarily not ready

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-marketing-api

We have been uploading to Facebook's Offline Conversion API for the past 3 weeks with no issues. Suddenly, Facebook is returning this error:

```
(#21009) The data set upload is temporarily not ready.
```

See below code for full JSON payload.

Our Auth Token is still valid. (e.g. Not expired, still valid)
According to this tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

```
# I had to remove these fields for privacy reasons
define('FACEBOOK_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN', 'YOUR TOKEN HERE');
define('FACEBOOK_PIXEL_OFFLINE_EVENT_SET_ID', 'YOUR PIXEL ID HERE');


# Be sure to change the email/name fields accordingly
$event_name='test-upload';
$data = array();
$data["match_keys"] = array();
$data["match_keys"]['email'] = hash('sha256', 'bob.ross@example.com');
$data["match_keys"]['fn'] = hash('sha256', 'bob');
$data["match_keys"]['ln'] = hash('sha256', 'ross');
$data["match_keys"]['gen'] = hash('sha256', 'm');
$data["event_time"] = time();
$data["event_name"] = $event_name;
$data["currency"] = "USD";
$data["value"] = '0.00';

// Turn Data to JSON
$data_json = json_encode(array($data));

// Fill available fields
$fields = array();
$fields['access_token'] = FACEBOOK_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN;
$fields['upload_tag'] = $event_name . '-' . time(); // You should set a tag here (feel free to adjust)
$fields['data'] = $data_json;


$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/' . FACEBOOK_PIXEL_OFFLINE_EVENT_SET_ID . '/events';
$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    // Replace with your offline_event_set_id
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/' . FACEBOOK_PIXEL_OFFLINE_EVENT_SET_ID . '/events', 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>  http_build_query($fields),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        //"content-type: multipart/form-data",
        "Accept: application/json"  ),
));


$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $response;
```

Expected result from Facebook:

```
{"id":"36485444079550","num_processed_entries":1}
```

Actual result from Facebook

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#21009) The data set upload is temporarily not ready.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 21009,
    "fbtrace_id": "GeofD5QsXdI"
  }
}
```

Comment: No answers yet. There is an ongoing discussion on Facebook Developers: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1052442614962359/

Answer (score 1):

I would add a comment instead of an "answer" but I don't quite have the points yet. The commenters on the Facebook thread (https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1052442614962359/) have had this magically resolve overnight, and I experienced the same (problem happening and no explanation, then magical resolution and no explanation). It seems like Facebook may have fixed whatever was causing the issue.

Comment: Calling it now...Facebook will close the ticket, say there wasn't enough information in the thread, and say the issue seems to be resolved without any explanation. ;)